# Check if UIImage returned from NINetworkImageView is valid

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, nimbus-ios

So I am making a call to pull an image from a photo server using Nimbus' NINetworkImageView object. I need to check if the object returned is valid. If it is not valid, the method

```
- (void) networkImageView:(NINetworkImageView *) imageView didLoadImage:(UIImage *) image {
```

returns a transparent UIImage object. I think the method is returning me a jpg image with clear pixels which is causing me the issue. I have tried the following checks to see if the image is transparent with no luck (All of the attempts below happen in the scope of the method above):

## Failed Attempt 1:

```
UIImageView *tempView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; 
if(tempView.alpha != 0.0f)
{   
    //the image is a valid (nonclear) image
}
else
{
     //the image is invalid (clear)
}
```

## Failed Attempt 2:

```
CGImageRef cgref = [[UIImage alloc] CGImage];
CIImage *cim = [[UIImage alloc] CIImage];

if(!([image CIImage] == cim && [image CGImage] == cgref))
{   
     //the image is a valid (nonclear) image
}
else
{
     //the image is invalid (clear)
}
```

## Failed Attempt 3:

```
if(image)
{   
     //the image is a valid (nonclear) image
}
else
{
     //the image is invalid (clear)
}
```

## Failed Attempt 4:

```
CGImageRef cgref = [image CGImage];
CIImage *cim = [image CIImage];

if(cim == nil && cgref == NULL)
{         
    //the image is invalid (clear)  
}
else
{
    //the image is a valid (nonclear) image
}
```

### Edit

I was able to pull the "Invalid image" from the simulator. The networkimageview method is returning a jpg image that is completely white. However, in the simulator it shows up as a clear picture, thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by not valid? The Nimbus docs say that there's also the delegate method `networkImageViewDidFailLoad:` - is that called in your case? Or do you mean that data is returned, but the image fails to load. In that case I'd expect either `image` to be `nil` or `image.size` to be `CGSizeZero`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that if the image is blank that it is "not valid". The image loads just fine but the image is clear. Using @beryllium instructions I was able to check the downloaded image. It is a JPG image without an alpha channel but for some reason, it is showing up as a blank image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can advice to save this image to disk and see it's alpha value in Photoshop/another graphic tool.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, NULL);
```

Now you can find this image in Photos app.

The following function saves UIImage with name `image.png` file in the user Document folder:

```
- (void)saveImage: (UIImage*)image
{
    if (image != nil)
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                       [NSString stringWithString: @"test.png"] ];
        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I go to get the photos? I am in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/media/ but the photos are in sql files.

Comment: hm. I'm really confused how to do this into Simulator. On device I just grab it with ImageCapture App

Comment: @Endama, i have updated answer. this code allow your to find image in Documents directory

Comment: Nevermind I found it, you need to go to the DCIM folder in the iPhoneSimulator folder. 

I checked the image, it is a jpg and it is a white color. When used in the app, however, it shows up as clear.

Comment: It does not have an alpha channel.

Comment: @Endama, one note. AFAIK, transparancy is not supported in jpg

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix. Using Beryllium's suggestion I downloaded the jpg image and then added it to the XCODE project. I named it BlankImage.jpg and added it. I then do the following comparison

```
- (void) networkImageView:(NINetworkImageView *) imageView didLoadImage:(UIImage *) image 
{

    if([ UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"BlankImage.JPG"], 1.0f ) isEqualToData: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f ) ])
    {
           //This is a blank image so handle that case
    }
    else
    {
           //This is a valid image
    }
}
```

The other option was to do crazy quartz stuff for pixel by pixel comparison. This worked just fine.